# Bubble sorting a string added to a buffer, that's in a struct C programming

Tags: c

It may be a bit confusing trying to explain what I'm doing, but the context is: I code on the side for a MUD (multi user dungeon) and I created a struct for player kills when they occur - which write to a .sav file, and then load every time the mud reboots into that struct.

The struct is like so:

```
    struct pkill_data
{
    PKILL_DATA       *next;
    char             *name;
    char             *victim;
    sh_int           wl;
    sh_int           location;
    sh_int           vclass;
    sh_int           vrace;
    sh_int           clevel;
    sh_int           vlevel;
    time_t           date;
};
```

And the create functions:

```
void update_pkill( CHAR_DATA* ch, CHAR_DATA* victim, int wl, int location, time_t date){
  PKILL_DATA* pkill;
  if (IS_NULLSTR( ch->name ) || IS_NULLSTR( victim->name ))
    return;
    pkill = new_pkill();
    pkill->name  = str_dup(ch->name);
    pkill->victim= str_dup(victim->name);
    pkill->vclass = victim->class;
    pkill->vrace = victim->race;
    pkill->date = date;
    pkill->vlevel = victim->level;
    pkill->clevel = ch->level;
    pkill->wl = wl;
    pkill->location = location;

    add_pkill(pkill);
    save_pkills();
}

PKILL_DATA* pkill_list;

void add_pkill( PKILL_DATA* pkill){
  if (pkill_list == NULL){
    pkill_list = pkill;
    pkill->next = NULL;
  }
  else{
    pkill->next = pkill_list;
    pkill_list = pkill;
  }
}
```

And the write/read functons:

```
void fwrite_pkill( FILE* fp, PKILL_DATA* pkill){
  fprintf( fp, "#PKILL %s~ %s~ %d %d %d %d %d %d %ld\n",
           pkill->name,
           pkill->victim,
           pkill->clevel,
           pkill->vlevel,
           pkill->vrace,
           pkill->vclass,
           pkill->wl,
           pkill->location,
           pkill->date);
}

void fread_pkill( FILE* fp, PKILL_DATA* pkill ){
  pkill->name    =       fread_string( fp );
  pkill->victim =       fread_string( fp );
  pkill->clevel =       fread_number( fp );
  pkill->vlevel =       fread_number( fp );
  pkill->vrace  =       fread_number( fp );
  pkill->vclass =       fread_number( fp );
  pkill->wl     =       fread_number( fp );
  pkill->location    =       fread_number( fp );
  pkill->date   =       fread_number( fp );
}

void save_pkills(){
  FILE *fp;
  PKILL_DATA* pkill = pkill_list;
  char path[128];

  fclose( fpReserve );
  sprintf( path, "%s%s", PKILL_DIR, PKILL_FILE);
  if ( ( fp = fopen( path, "w" ) ) == NULL ){
    fp = fopen( NULL_FILE, "r" );
    fclose (fp);
    perror( path );
    return;
  }
/* loop through pkills and save */
  for (; pkill; pkill = pkill->next ){
    fwrite_pkill( fp, pkill);
  }
  fprintf( fp, "#END\n" );
  fclose( fp );
  fpReserve = fopen( NULL_FILE, "r" );
}
```

And the load functions:

```
PKILL_DATA* get_pkill( char* name, char* victim ){
  PKILL_DATA* pkill = pkill_list;

  for (;pkill; pkill = pkill->next){
    if (str_cmp(name, pkill->name))
      continue;
    else if (!IS_NULLSTR(victim) && str_cmp(pkill->victim, victim))
      continue;
    return pkill;
  }
  return NULL;
}

void load_pkills(){
  PKILL_DATA* pkill;
  FILE *fp;
  char path[128];
  char letter;
  char* word;

  fclose( fpReserve );
  sprintf( path, "%s%s", PKILL_DIR, PKILL_FILE);
  if ( ( fp = fopen( path, "r" ) ) == NULL ){
    fp = fopen( NULL_FILE, "r" );
    fclose (fp);
    perror( path );
    return;
  }

  for (;;){
    letter              = fread_letter( fp );
    if ( letter != '#' ){
      bug( "load_pkill: # not found.", 0 );
      exit( 1 );
    }
    word   = feof( fp ) ? "END" : fread_word( fp );
    if ( !str_cmp(word, "END"))
      break;
    else if (!str_cmp(word, "PKILL")){
      pkill = new_pkill();
      fread_pkill( fp, pkill );
      add_pkill( pkill );
    }
  }
  fclose( fp );
  fpReserve = fopen( NULL_FILE, "r" );

  prune_pkall();
}
```

All of the above info may be too much info. Pretty much, the basic outline is I save everything to a file, which loads into a struct/table whenever the mud reboots or when a pkill is created, so I can pull from that list at any given time.

I want to be able to view these pkills by date created, (which is pkill->date), after they've been added into the buffer for viewing. I'm unsure how to do a bubble list with a buffer or how to sort a buffer before printing to the user.

below, add_buf is just a bool used elsewhere:

```
bool add_buf(BUFFER *buffer, char *string)
{
    int len, oldsize = buffer->size;
    char *oldstr = buffer->string;
    if (buffer->state == BUFFER_OVERFLOW)
        return FALSE;
    len = strlen(buffer->string) + strlen(string) + 1;
    while (len >= buffer->size)
    {
        buffer->size    = get_size(buffer->size + 1);
        {
            if (buffer->size == -1)
            {
                buffer->size = oldsize;
                buffer->state = BUFFER_OVERFLOW;
                bug("buffer overflow past size %d",buffer->size);
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
    if (buffer->size != oldsize)
    {
        buffer->string  = alloc_mem(buffer->size);
        strcpy(buffer->string,oldstr);
        free_mem(oldstr,oldsize);
    }
    strcat(buffer->string,string);
    return TRUE;
}
```

And onto the ACTUAL question - how can I use a bubble sort within a string that's in a struct? This is what I have so far:

```
  PKILL_DATA* pkill;
  BUFFER* buffer;
  char buf[MIL];


  buffer = new_buf();
  for (pkill = pkill_list ; pkill ; pkill = pkill->next ){
    if (str_cmp(pkill->name, argument))
      continue;
    sprintf(buf, "%s %s %d %d %d %d %d %d %ld\n\r", pkill->name, pkill->victim, pkill->clevel, pkill->vlevel, pkill->vrace, pkill->vclass, pkill->wl, pkill->location, pkill->date);
  }
  page_to_char(buf_string(buffer),ch);
  free_buf(buffer);
```

As one might could imagine, it's not sorted at all in any way, and lists them from top of file to bottom of file, or however which way they were loaded into the string/struct in the first place.

Comment: Does it *have* to be bubble sort? If not, you can just use `qsort` from `stdlib.h` along with a custom comparison callback.

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to sort from all this mess...

Comment: @DrewMcGowen : It doesn't have to be a bubble sort - that's just the only thing I could find that would potentially work, I guess?

I'll take a look at qsort. Thanks.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen `qsort` doesn't work with linked lists, right? One would need to re-implement the functionality to handle them, including swapping next/previous pointers to account for a difference in order.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune I completely missed that - correct, `qsort` doesn't work for linked lists.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune forgive me, but I'm new(er) at linked lists. Do you have a suggest on how it should be handled if I were to re-write the whole function? Not looking to be baby fed - just a place to start!